# How to encourage optimiser to pick solution with fewest transactions (i.e. minimise cardinality)

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, constraint-programming, mosek

I have a linear model that is seeking to move 'units' between 'cells' in an optimal manner. Each transfer costs $2 plus 1% of the unit amount transferred.

Lets say a target cell requires 100 units and can receive it from any of 10 source cells. How can I encourage the optimiser to make a single transfer of 100 units from one of the source cells (total cost 2+1) rather than transferring 10 units from each of the valid source cells (total cost 20+1)?

I've implemented this in matlab using mosek if it matters.

(Apologies if the question is a bit vague, this is all self-taught and I'm not sure how to ask this unambiguously with the correct terminology. Happy to repost this question on a more appropriate SE if there is one.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard Integer programming called the **Fixed Charge Transportation Problem**.

Let's say that there are `S` suppliers and `D` customers with Demands.
Each supplier `i` has `S_i` units and each customer `j` has a Demand `D_j`

You need two types of decision variables.

- `Xij` is the amount that goes from Supplier i to Customer j.
- But there is a also the fixed cost that we have to take care of. `Fij = 2` ($2 for each supplier that ships units.) Let the fixed cost variable be

  - `Y_ij = 1` if Supplier i sends a non-zero number of units to Customer j.
  - `Y_ij = 0` Otherwise.

#### Formulation

```
Objective Minimize sum of all Subsets.
 Min sum (F_ij Yij) + sum Cij*Xij

Subject to:

    Sum over i Xij >= D_j for each customer j //Demand satisfaction
    Sum over j Xij <= S_i for each supplier i //Supply limitation

    // if you use a supplier for a customer, Yij has to become 1.
    Yij >= Xij for each i and each j 

Yij binary, Xij >=0
```

You will find more on Fixed Charge Integer Programming problems in any standard OR textbook. Look for the chapter where Integer Programming is introduced.

Hope that helps you move forward.

Answer (score 1):

the point is which is the objective function that you want to minimize or maximize. If you only want to reduce the number of transfer, you must minimize the number of non-zero transfers: assuming you have a variable $x_{ij}$ for the transfer from $i$ to $j$, then you should minimize $\sum y_{ij}$ where $y_{ij}$ is a binary variable that takes value $0$ when $x_{ij}=0$, $1$ otherwise.

I guess you can formulate the overall model as a min-cost flow between cells, possibly with additional constraints and with a non-trivial objective function.

(By the way, if you need help you might also contact us at mosek on our google forum...)

Comment: How do I set up $y_{ij}$?